# List of primary, secondary and tertiary alcohol

Tags: alcohols

Is there a list of primary, secondary and tertiary alcohols examples anywhere?

Comment: There can be infinitely many alcohols of each kind. Why would you want a list anyway? It's like asking for a list of instances you went to the restroom.

Comment: I would like to see some examples of them.

Comment: Is Google blocked in your country?

Comment: I googled it and kept getting results that had nothing to do with Alcohols.

Comment: Try [this](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Purdue/Purdue_Chem_26100%3A_Organic_Chemistry_I_(Wenthold)/Chapter_10%3A_Alcohols/10.1_Structure_and_Classification_of_Alcohols).

Comment: If you know, what primary, secondary, tertiary alcohol is, you need not a list. If you do not know it, learn it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are 2 hydrogen atoms connected to the carbinol carbon(the one with a hydroxyl group) its a primary alcohol.

If there is only one hydrogen atom connected to the carbinol carbon it's a secondary alcohol.

The one with no hydrogen atoms is a tertiary alcohol.

Now you can make the list yourself.

Comment: Unless the carbon belongs to aromatic  system, in such a case we consider it rather as a phenolic than alcoholic group.